# How to vertically center page title text within parent banner image?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a page title for every page of my website, which by default is placed within the banner image for that page. I have instituted solutions that center these page titles, but the code implementations are inconsistent between the pages. The biggest problem is centering for mobile, where things can get a bit wonky from page to page. I used this rule previously to center text, but it causes inconsistencies based on device screen width:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) { #banner-area { padding-top: 85px; }}
```

Effectively, this pushed content down to the correct position on phone screen sizes. However, it seems a bit "hacky" and inelegant. I was later turned onto the translateY property, and instituted this code to center the text vertically:

```
/* Page 1 */

@media screen and (max-width: 769px) { #page-title { transform: translateY(-30px); }} 
@media screen and (min-width: 770px) { #page-title { transform: translateY(10px); }} 

/* Pages 2 through 7 */

#page-title { transform: translateY(50%); } /* or below... */
@media screen and (min-width: 770px) { #page-title { transform: translateY(50%); }}
```

Corresponding HTML:

```
<div id="banner-area">
   <div id="page-title">
```

Is this the correct way to write this CSS rule for centering vertically, or can someone else offer a better solution? It bugs me that page 1 has its own set of rules, where the rest are more or less identical in achieving the centering effect. Something that would allow me to get rid of that banner-area padding hack would be great - I need a one-size-fits-all rule for multiple device screen sizes.

Comment: do you have HTML and CSS you are using now?

Comment: I don't exactly have access to the site template's HTML (using Squarespace) without using DevTools/Web Inspector. The parent element is #banner-area, the child being #page-title

Comment: Added the very basic HTML. Doesn't have a ton of bearing on the selectors used in the CSS, in terms of the question

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit vague, and without proper html and css we can't give you the answer you might want. However if I understand correctly this is what you are after:

```
#page-title {
   margin-top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

or

```
parent {
    position: relative;
}

#page-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

With a transform the % refer to the size of the div, instead of the size of the parent.

Alternatively you could use flexbox on the parent element:

```
parent {
   display: flex;
   align-itens: center; // Vertical
   justify-content: center; // Horizontal
}
```

Once again, without context is hard to say which of these is the best solution, if any.

Comment: Remember the first and the second solution is not cross browsers specially in the androids.

Comment: @abdallaarbab Why not? Transform works perfectly fine on all modern browsers.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=translate. I am not saying these way do not work. I am saying that flex box is the future of centering stuff cross browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=align-items http://caniuse.com/#search=justify-content

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these:
HTML:

```
<div class="page-title">
  <h2>Page Title</h2>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.page-title{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Does that align-items property align the corresponding title vertically, horizontally, or both?

Comment: align-items:center; align the corresponding title vertically

to center it horizontally : justify-content: center;